# How to read a geojson file in javascript and get min or max of property?

Tags: javascript, math, geojson

I'm new to js sorry if it's a stupid question. I guess there is two parts to my question.

What is the simplest way to read a geojson file with javascript ?

Right now I'm using :

```
var centrisData = $.getJSON( "Path to geojson");
```

My file looks something like that:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Maison\u00a0",
        "utilisation": "null",
        "piecesBeta": "20.0",
        "price": 3995000.0,
        "prixPiece_beta": 199750.0,
      },
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Condo\u00a0",
        "utilisation": "null",
        "piecesBeta": "6.0",
        "price": 448900.0,
        "prixPiece_beta": 74816.67
      }
    }
```

I want to be able to get the min and max of the property "price". What would be the easiest way to do so ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all of the features and keep and store the current minimum and maximum prices as variables.

```js
const centrisData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Maison\u00a0",
        "utilisation": "null",
        "piecesBeta": "20.0",
        "price": 3995000.0,
        "prixPiece_beta": 199750.0,
      },
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Condo\u00a0",
        "utilisation": "null",
        "piecesBeta": "6.0",
        "price": 448900.0,
        "prixPiece_beta": 74816.67
      }
    }
  ]
};
let min = Infinity, max = -min;
for(const {properties: {price}} of centrisData.features){
  min = Math.min(min, price);
  max = Math.max(max, price);
}
console.log("Min:", min);
console.log("Max:", max);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to figure out how to call or how to load the geojson file as to do the same thing you did but without having to copy the whole geojson object in my script.

Comment: I tried to load it like that : 

const centrisData = $.getJSON( "data/proprio_dataset.geojson", function( json ) {
   console.log("Success");
   });

But got a centrisData.features is not iterable. Guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You should be using `json.features` in the callback.